# my google analytics shows data from realtime stream but no hits in standard report

Tags: google-analytics

1. I can see traffics in realtime stream, there are active users on my site.
2. But I can't see visitor information in standard report.
3. My site was set up long times ago, and previously data collecting works fine, so it shouldn't be the 'new property not display data within 24 hours' issue.
4. I did modify my property yesterday, I've added 'referral exclusion' item, and deleted few minutes later.
5. There're no filters in my view anymore.
6. No hits collected mostly like happen after I've done item 4(change property).

How can I fix this issue, any ideas?

Comment: Have you waited at least some hours to be sure that it is not some processing time issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your monthly quota? (admin > property settings > property hit volume > last month).

In the free version of GA you've 10 million hits per month per property.(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas).

Moreover if you send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days.
(https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)

Maybe one of these conditions is the cause of the issue.